# Bootstrap Mobile menu button hide when scroll

Tags: responsive-design, menu, bootstrap-4, responsive

I have this responsive website, but for the menu part in Mobile when I scroll it doesn't show the buttons anymore, I should scroll back to the top to get to the buttons.

I don't know why the buttons in the mobile menu don't scroll within the screen.

HTML

```css
    /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Header
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#header {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 999;
}
#header .header-content {
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 1170px;
 padding: 20px 0;
 width: 100%;
 -moz-transition: padding 0.3s;
 -o-transition: padding 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition: padding 0.3s;
 transition: padding 0.3s;
}
#header .logo {
 float: right;
 font-size:24px;
 font-weight:700;
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 letter-spacing:7px;
}
#header.fixed {
 background-color: #181818;
 padding: 0;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s;
 -o-transition: background-color 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s;
 transition: background-color 0.3s;
}
#header.fixed a {
 color: #fff;
}
#header.fixed .header-content {
 border-bottom: 0;
}
#header.fixed .nav-toggle {
 top: 18px;
 color: #000;
}
.navigation.open {
 opacity: 0.9;
 visibility: visible;
 -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
 -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
 transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.navigation {
 float: left;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.navigation li {
 display: inline-block;
}
.navigation a {
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-left: 40px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navigation a:hover, .navigation a.active {
 color: #fff;
}
.nav-toggle {
 display: none;
 height: 44px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: fixed;
 left: 5%;
 text-indent: 100%;
 top: 32px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 width: 44px;
 z-index: 99999;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}
.nav-toggle:before, .nav-toggle:after {
 border-radius: 50%;
 content: "";
 height: 100%;
 left: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
 -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
 transform: translateZ(0);
 -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
 -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
 -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
 transition-property: transform;
}
.nav-toggle:before {
 background-color: #1192cf;
 -moz-transform: scale(1);
 -ms-transform: scale(1);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 transform: scale(1);
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
 transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.nav-toggle:after {
 background-color: #1192cf;
 -moz-transform: scale(0);
 -ms-transform: scale(0);
 -webkit-transform: scale(0);
 transform: scale(0);
 -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
 -o-transition-duration: 0s;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
 transition-duration: 0s;
}
.nav-toggle span {
 background-color: #fff;
 bottom: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 3px;
 left: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 right: auto;
 top: 50%;
 width: 18px;
 z-index: 10;
 -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.nav-toggle span:before, .nav-toggle span:after {
 background-color: #fff;
 content: "";
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
 -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
 transform: translateZ(0);
 -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s;
 -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
 transition: transform 0.3s;
}
.nav-toggle span:before {
 -moz-transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(0deg);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(0deg);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(0deg);
 transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(0deg);
}
.nav-toggle span:after {
 -moz-transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
 -ms-transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
 transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
}
.nav-toggle.close-nav:before {
 -moz-transform: scale(0);
 -ms-transform: scale(0);
 -webkit-transform: scale(0);
 transform: scale(0);
}
.nav-toggle.close-nav:after {
 -moz-transform: scale(1);
 -ms-transform: scale(1);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 transform: scale(1);
}
.nav-toggle.close-nav span {
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
.nav-toggle.close-nav span:before, .nav-toggle.close-nav span:after {
 background-color: #fff;
}
.nav-toggle.close-nav span:before {
 -moz-transform: translateY(0) rotate(45deg);
 -ms-transform: translateY(0) rotate(45deg);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(0) rotate(45deg);
 transform: translateY(0) rotate(45deg);
}
.nav-toggle.close-nav span:after {
 -moz-transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
 -ms-transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
 transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
 #header .header-content {
 width: 90%;
 padding:20px 0px;
}
 #header.fixed a {
 color: #000;
}
 .nav-toggle {
 display: block;
}
 .navigation {
 position: fixed;
 background-color: #000;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 99999;
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0s 0.5s;
 transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0s 0.5s;
}
 .navigation .primary-nav {
 position: relative;
 top: 45%;
 -moz-transform: translateY(-45%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-45%);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-45%);
 transform: translateY(-45%);
}
 .navigation li {
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
 .navigation a {
 display: block;
 font-size: 25px;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
}
 .flex-control-nav {
 bottom: 20px;
}
}
```

```html
   <header id="header">
    <div class="header-content clearfix"> <a class="logo" href="index.html"><img style="logo-size" src="images/logo-awaed.png" width="150px" height="62px"></a>
      <nav class="navigation" role="navigation">
        <ul class="primary-nav">
          <li><a href="#intro">عن الشركة</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">خدماتنا</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">اتصل بنا</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <a href="#" class="nav-toggle">Menu<span></span></a> </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Read the Bootstrap documentation and use the navbar and the navbar components Bootstrap 4 provides.

Here's a working navbar example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/